# Secure variables protected by Linux kernel

Tags: linux, security, linux-kernel

Is there a possibility to place variables under the custody of the Linux kernel?

E.g. counters that may only be incremented, variables that can be written to but only read after authentication.

Ideally with persistency after reboot and unalterable between boots.

I could think of a kernel module that allows access to the variables via /proc filesystem and storing the values in the kernel keyring.

However I could not find a solution for this.

Usecase would be e.g. software eFuses https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFUSE and the ability to securely store variables from user space.

Comment: See if `man keyrings` (and SEE ALSOs) can answer some of your needs.

Comment: Can you give a sample use case?

Comment: A sample usecase would be an invalid password retry counter or a write only variable e.g. enter a password that can be used by an application but cannot be read back by a regular user or only after authentication.

Comment: I found keyrings with the keyctl utility to be a very good solution. Thanks for pointing that out! @StéphaneChazelas

Answer (score 1):

You have got Redis for storing data structures and getting them after reboot, as the service saves the cache when going down.

https://redis.io

Redis does not use proc, runs at user land level, and you talk with it by default at 6379/TCP.

There are also APIs/extensions for a few languages, including python and PHP.

You can do also some diagnostics, and send some commands by telneting to it/`wget`/`curl`.

It can be password protected.

to install it on Debian

```
sudo apt-get install redis-server
```

.

> Redis is an open source (BSD licensed), in-memory data structure
>   store, used as a database, cache and message broker. It supports data
>   structures such as strings, hashes, lists, sets, sorted sets with
>   range queries, bitmaps, hyperloglogs and geospatial indexes with
>   radius queries. Redis has built-in replication, Lua scripting, LRU
>   eviction, transactions and different levels of on-disk persistence...

From this [Redis Quick Guide](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/redis/redis_quick_guide.htm)

> Redis is an open source, advanced key-value store and an apt solution
>   for building highperformance, scalable web applications.
>
> Redis has three main peculiarities that sets it apart.
>
> Redis holds its database entirely in the memory, using the disk only
>   for persistence.
>
> Redis has a relatively rich set of data types when compared to many
>   key-value data stores.
>
> Redis can replicate data to any number of slaves.

Comment: Whilst redis can indeed be used as a type database, there is not much to it that lends itself to a secure solution as per the OP's requirements...

Comment: @Pedro It is indeed a type database ; however it is not clear wether the requirements of the OP are realistic, and thus the answer as it is as redis being a suggestion for a persistent DB from a application usage point of view.Lastly, a couple of points. The infra-structure is just a secure as you design it, the fs, connecting between the frontend and backend can be encrypted either with IPsec or a SSL proxy, and you are not even obliged to place things in clear text in the redis database. big organisations are using redis. At the end of the day it also depends on how big is the data, et al.

Comment: understood. my reading of the question suggested a security focused solution, hence my attempt to respond. also the implicit direction of 'held by the kernel, therefore secure' is a misconception that I wanted to clear. no intention to step on your toes, just thought I could contribute further. however, and for the sake of openness, I originally voted down your answer since your suggestion of using redis would be as good as sqlite or text files. I did not see how it fit the security aspect of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Attending to your original question and subsequent comments, the answer is no.

> Is there a possibility to place variables under the custody of the Linux kernel?
>
> Ideally with persistency after reboot and unalterable between boots.
>
> I could think of a kernel module that allows access to the variables via /proc filesystem and storing the values in the kernel keyring.

If you are looking for a way to store data securely, then you need a database of some kind and the means to ensure integrity of the data stored - which usually involves cryptography. This in itself creates several problems that need to be addressed carefully, such as key management, storage encryption, etc.

The kernel offers very few options for persistent data storage. There's keyring as mentioned which might help, but its purpose is slightly different. I have never studied the security of this kind of subsystem, so I would not be able to comment about its strength for your use case.

Comment: IMO the problem is actually not having persistency.

Answer (score 0):

You have Redis for putting away information structures and getting them after reboot, as the administration spares the store while going down. Just go to the below link is helpful for you.

https://hackr.io/tutorials/learn-redis